# String Sort based on some Format

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a string which needs to be sorted based on the `sort_fmt`. Ex: If the string is 'abdcdfs' & the sort_fmt is 'dacg'. Upon sort, the output should be 'ddacfbs'. As you see, there might be characters in input string that are not present in the order string and vice-versa. The characters of input string that are not present in the order string should come at the end of the output string in any order.

Here's what I have written. It works, It's O(n*m) algo. I was wondering is there are better & shorter ways to do this? Maybe use `itertools`?

```
def sort_str(s, sort_fmt):
    sorted_str = ''
    str_hash   = dict()

    # O(n)
    for ch in s:
        if ch in str_hash:
            str_hash[ch] += 1
        else:
            str_hash[ch] = 1

    # O(m) + O(1) where m<=n
    for ch in sort_fmt:
        if ch in str_hash:
            cnt = str_hash[ch]
            sorted_str += cnt * ch

    # O(n)
    for ch in s:
        if ch not in sort_fmt:
            sorted_str += ch
    return sorted_str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sort_str('abdcdfs', 'dacg')
```

Comment: O(n) sort? Are you quite sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to implement [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which is indeed O(n) under certain conditions. However your implementation has two bugs near the end which mean that the actual time complexity of your implementation is O(n<sup>2</sup> + n*m):

```
for ch in s:
    if ch not in sort_fmt:  # <--- "in" requires a linear search. O(n*m)
        sorted_str += ch    # <--- Ouch! Concatenation! O(n^2)
```

- You are constructing the result in an inefficient way because you are using concatenation in a loop.
- Using `in` on a string is linear in the length of the string, and you are doing this in a loop.

Try this instead. It requires Python 2.7 or newer because of the use of `collections.Counter`, but the `Counter` can easily be replaced with a `defaultdict` for older versions of Python):

```
from collections import Counter

def sort_str(s, sort_fmt):
    counter = Counter(s)
    d = set(sort_fmt)
    result = ''.join(c * counter[c] for c in sort_fmt)
    result += ''.join(c for c in s if c not in d)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sort_str('abdcdfs', 'dacg')
```

Here's a more concise way to get the result you want if you drop the requirement that it should be O(n):

```
>>> d = dict((v,k) for (k,v) in enumerate('dacg'))
>>> sorted('abdcdfs', key = lambda c:d.get(c, len(d)))
['d', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'f', 's']
```

Comment: Any reason for the second dict? It should work with tuples right? d = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate('dacg'))

Comment: @Peter Gibson: No, no reasons, that was just a typo. :) Fixed, thanks.

Comment: so the best one can do is O(n*m)?

Comment: @MovieYoda: Why do you think that one is O(n*m)?

Comment: @MovieYoda: The counting sort, when implemented correctly, is O(n + m).

Comment: @Mark Byers: There is no need to calculate len(d) in the lambda. In fact, I tested, and both algorithms scale very similarly and yours is slower (even without the len(d). :) It could be because sorted(is guaranteed to leave the rest of the string in order. They results are not the same for both algorithms.

Comment: No, my bad, they *are* the same. The man difference in time is probably due to that that your return a list, and the posters return a string.

Comment: (or not. The above implementation is specialized for counting sort, while your implementations uses a generic sort to implement it, perhaps that's why). (Could anybody explain to me when a counting sort would be actually useful? It only works if you have data that is all the same length and has loads of duplicates, right?)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: My first implementation is counting sort and is hopefully O(n+m) and the second uses a generic sort. Counting sort is useful if the number of different elements in the input is bounded but the length of input is unbounded. These constraints imply that there will be many duplicates for long input strings.

Comment: Yeah, astonishingly they seem to both be slower than OP's. But they both scale the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the complexity of sorted. This works

```
def sort_str(s, frmt):
    l = len(frmt)
    return sorted(s, key = lambda x: frmt.index(x) if x in frmt else l)
```